# Reformulate absolute value as quadratic problem

Tags: absolute-value, quadratic-programming

I'm looking for standard approach to reformulate this objective function.
The aim is to find values of $x_i$ that are close to either $y_i$ or $-y_i$ ($y_i$s are known) in a least-squares sense:

$argmin_{x_i \in \mathbf{x}} \sum\| |x_i| - |y_i| \|^2$

Specifically, can the inner absolute value be rewritten in a simpler way to convert it into a QP?

One way would be to approximate the objective as:
$argmin_{x_i \in \mathbf{x}} \sum\| x_i^2 - y_i^2\|^2$ but it is no longer quadratic.

Comment: Two remarks: 1. what you say "close to either $y_i$ or $-y_i$" is not the same what you write "close to $|y_i|$", because in the first formulation the choice of the sign of $y_i$ is also an optimization parameter, and 2. it is already quadratic in $x$ as you wrote it. Just call $t_i=|y_i|$, they are given.

Comment: Thanks A.G.. Regarding the 1st remark, you're right, I had missed out the abs symbol around $x_i$ in the first formulation. Fixed now.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to define $z_i=x_i^2$ and to have QP with extra $z\ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, that would make the problem a QCQP. Thanks A.G. will try this out.